# Unique Permutations of Binary Numbers

Tags: algorithm, permutation

I have a binary number, for example 1010, and I want to know the number of unique permutations of that binary number.

For example, 1010 has 6 unique permutations:

- 0011
- 0101
- 1010
- 0110
- 1001
- 1100

While 1000 has 4 unique permutations:

- 1000
- 0100
- 0010
- 0001

So, given a binary string of length `X`, with `N` 1s and `X-N` 0s, how many unique permutations are there?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [math.se]

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is equivalent to the problem, "for a set containing X elements, how many distinct n-element subsets of it can be formed?" Where the X element set is "the indices of the binary string", and the n-element subset is "the indices of the binary string which will be assigned a 1". Looking at the formula for the [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), the answer is "X choose N", or `(X!) / (N! * (X-N)!)`